# Number of trees with some restrictions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

In an exercise I am asked to say how many trees of 6 vertex are there, taking into account that there has to be four vertex of degree 2. After some attempts, I have reached the conclusion that there is none, but I'm not sure it is right. Here is what I have done:

Since the tree has $6$ vertex, there has to be $5$ edges, and taking into account that $2|E| = \sum_{v \in V}{deg}(v)$, I obtain that there are $2$ edges of degree $1$. However, no matter how much I try, I end up with the fact that or there is a vertex of degree $3$ or there are more vertex of degree $1$. Since there are supposedly two vertex of degree $1$, there are two options: they are joint with the same vertex or not. In the first case, that vertex of degree $2$ cannot be joint with any other vertex since the maximum degree according to the exercise is $2$. And since the graph is connected, this means that one of those two vertex of degree $1$ are not actually of that degree. In the second case, a similar reasoning turns up to be something with no concordance with the conditions of the exercise. Does this mean that there aren't any graphs with these restrictions?

Comment: For any $n\geq 2$ there is one and exactly one $n$-vertex tree with two vertices of degree $1$ and all others of degree 2. So it looks like in the last part starting from "In the second case, a similar reasoning turns up..." you made some mistake. But since we don't know your argument there, it is hard to point to a specific mistake.

Comment: I'll take into account that fact. However, how to prove that statement?

Comment: Try to find this unique tree first. It is not a very convoluted one.

Comment: I have just found it, it is much easier that one could expect at once